# Convert message url into youtube video

Tags: php, youtube

I want to change every YouTube link inside a message to the video itself.

I get all messages from the database in a variable `$status_message`

i allready tried something like this, but it didnt work i dont even know if this is the right way im a beginner.

```
<?php

function convert($status_message){
return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
} 

echo "<div id=status_message>" . convert($status_message) . "</div>";

?>
```

But i couldnt get this work, i want it work like if someone submit

Hello this is a test
this://www.youtube...urll.. (Load the video directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this

```
echo "<div id=status_message>" . $status_message . "</div>";

$('#status_message').html(function(i, url) {

    return url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});
```